# Android Lollipop's BeginDelayedTransition not always working

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I have an activity which starts with a number of invisible views. I then use handler.postDelayed to make every view visible again with a slide animation and the BeginDelayedTransition method. Normally all the views should slide in, one after another. Anyway i noticed that depending on the time interval between each runnable and even depending on the device i test the app on, some of the animations are totally skipped and the view just appears without any transition. I think it may be related to the time it takes to beginDelayedTransition to calculate the changes in the visibility thus instantiating the correct animation. 
Is anyone experiencing the same problem? Is there any workaround for this, other than calling a TranslateAnimation every time?
Thanks in advance!